# Как правильно писать и употреблять?

Tags: орфография

"По-классике" и  "по классике". Оба варианта являются правильными и  используются в зависимости от контекста? Если да, то приведите, пожалуйста, примеры предложений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно: **по классике.** Слова с дефисным написанием не существует.

Правило: http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=68#pp68

9. Пишутся через дефис наречия с приставкой по-, образованные **от полных форм прилагательных и от местоимений и оканчивающиеся на -ому/-ему, -ки, -ьи:** по-видимому; по-пустому; работать по-новому; по-прежнему; пусть будет по-вашему; советовать по-дружески; говорить по-французски; хитрить по-лисьи, а также по-латыни.

***По классике*** — это падежная форма **существительного (Д.п., предлог ПО)**, иногда она употребляется в значении наречия: *учиться по классике* (по классическим методикам). Но в любом случае написание раздельное.

Примеры:

Она тосковала **по классике,** по настоящему искусству. [Елена Гиль. «Она летит легко, проворно, так радостно парит она» (2003) // «Вестник США», 2003.06.25]

Все они заканчиваются в середине школы, и дальше дети продолжают **учиться по классике.** [Наши дети: Дошколята и младшие школьники (форум) (2005)]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ